# forece refresh client page from server side

Tags: php, client, refresh, client-side

How may I refresh current client view page from the server side?
for example, if I want to force refresh for page that is viewing now for all the clients, so they can view the new content. and I want to do this refresh in the time that I want using PHP.

Is it possible??

Comment: AFAIK you can't send a `response` until they `request`

Comment: @legendinmaking is right.  You are going to have to send a request via JavaScript, JQuery etc to the PHP page to refresh it.  Once PHP is rendered, it is done, and cannot refresh "itself"

Comment: Not possible. Once the page has been sent to the browser it is then down to the user to request further pages etc.

Comment: You could use AJAX and/or long polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Web Sockets. You can use either PHP Sockets with [this](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) or [this](https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket)

I think php Sockets would require you to have a PHP version of 5.3 or above.

If you don't have PHP v5.3 or above you can use [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/) with [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Long Pooling is also one of the option, but that won't be a good solution considering the number of requests your server would be getting. Also the user's bandwidth usage will go high.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the behavior in two ways:

WebSockets - If all your clients connect via web sockets, you have a direct connection between the client and the server. You'll need to get creative with timing, but you can certainly send a command at any time requiring a refresh. This requires that you implement web sockets in PHP http://socketo.me/ and JavaScript.

Polling - You can set up the client to send an AJAX request every x seconds. The server responds with a bool value which the AJAX success handler uses to determine whether it should refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the page at a certain interval, include this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Change "5" to whatever number of seconds you prefer.

If you want to refresh *only* when things have changed, you'd need to get some Javascript involved on the client - e.g. an Ajax request to a URL that asks if there's new data since page load, and refreshes if necessary.