# How to send user to a login page without waiting for a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html, events

How to send user to a login page if his account logged in from another device / browser (without waiting for a page refresh)?

I want the page to be available at the same time in only one browser at a time. If a user entered from somewhere else, the previous device must be forced to open authorization form.
I think is possible to use something like [Server-sent events](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_serversentevents.asp), but this method is not supported in IE, and I do not know how to use it.

I would be grateful for the help.

Comment: you could try a client reload from server side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243296/forece-refresh-client-page-from-server-side

Comment: @christopher2007 Thank you! So I have to choose between the socket and pooling (AJAX). And if I understand correctly, that the sockets better than pooling in terms of performance?

Comment: yes, the sockets solution is pretty accurate in terms of performance. I would recomment you to take a look at [php-websocket](https://github.com/nekudo/php-websocket). I also used this once and the usage is very userfriendly.